# Office 2013 programs hang when alt key is pressed

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am using Office 2013 on a Dell Windows 8 laptop.  When I press the ALT key in either Word or Excel the document I am editing will immediately hang (e.g. trying to do Alt-tab, Alt-F, etc).  Other programs are still editable, but the only way I can proceed with the Office program is to right-click the Word or Excel program icon in my task bar and select "Close program".  If I have made changes to the document I will then be prompted if I want to save the changes, and if I press Cancel in this window I can resume editing.  I have tried disabling all Add-ins but the problem persists.  Does anyone know how to fix this problems?

Update: I am using Office 2013 Home and Business, if that makes a difference.  Also, I discovered that if I Alt-tab to the desktop (e.g. minimize all open windows), and then Alt-tab to the hanging Excel or Word document, then things work ok again.  Not sure if that will help find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Does the same issue occur in Notepad or Wordpad?

Comment: I just tested both Notepad and Wordpad and they both work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that your installation of Office 2013 is corrupted. You can access Office 2013 installation, setup, and repair downloads [on this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/download-back-up-restore-microsoft-office-products-FX103427465.aspx). I'd also reccomend if you have not, to [upgrade to Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial) (this is free).

Comment: I think these are good suggestions for troubleshooting, but what evidence is there that these issues arise from these stated problems? This type of evidence would make this more of an **answer** to the question rather than troubleshooting.

Comment: I am updated to Windows 8.1.  Using the Excel ribbon, I went to File / Account / Office Updates.  Iinstalled some updates that were waiting, then restarted and OFfice now reports that everything is up to date.  But the problem continued.

Comment: That isn't reinstalling

Comment: Next I tried to repair Office from Programs and Features in the Control Panel, as outlined in the instructions halfway down this page:  http://support.microsoft.com/gp/office-2013-click-to-run.  But still no luck.

Comment: @DaveRook - I will try to reinstall next.

Comment: I've uninstalled and re-installed, and the problem persists.